# For Loop efficiency when using enumerate or other functions

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, enumeration

Someone suggested replacing my:

```
for m in hazardflr:
    safetiles.append((m, step))
    i = 0
```

with a more reasonable approach such as:

```
for i, m in enumerate(hazardflr):
    safetiles.append((m, step))
```

if there is a way to make this more efficient,

I see now how this saves code lines and says the same thing. I didn't know about `enum()` function. My question is now if are there any other modifications I can do to make this code more efficient and line saving?

```
def missingDoor(trapdoor, roomwidth, roomheight, step):        
    safezone = []
    hazardflr = givenSteps(roomwidth, step, True)
    safetiles = []

    for i, m in enumerate(hazardflr):
        safetiles.append((m,step))
        while i < len(safetiles):
            nextSafe = safetiles[i]
            if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, nextSafe[0], nextSafe[1]):
                if trapdoor[nextSafe[0]/roomwidth][nextSafe[0]%roomwidth] is "0":
                    if nextSafe[0] not in safezone:
                        safezone.append(nextSafe[0])
                    for e in givenSteps(roomwidth, nextSafe[0], True):
                        if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, e, nextSafe[0]):
                            if trapdoor[e/roomwidth][e%roomwidth] is "0" and (e,nextSafe[0]) not in safetiles:
                                safetiles.append((e,nextSafe[0]))
            i += 1  
    return sorted(safezone)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## assign `nextSafe[0]` to a local variable

Your code is 9 times (if I count correctly) using expression `nextSafe[0]`.

Accessing an item from a list is more expensive than picking the value from a variable.

Modification as follows:

```
for i,m in enumerate(hazardflr):
safetiles.append((m,step))
    while i < len(safetiles):
        nextSafe = safetiles[i]
        ns0 = nextSafe[0]
        if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, ns0, nextSafe[1]):
            if trapdoor[ns0/roomwidth][ns0 % roomwidth] is "0":
                if ns0 not in safezone:
                    safezone.append(ns0)
                for e in givenSteps(roomwidth,ns0,True):
                    if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, e, ns0):
                        if trapdoor[e/roomwidth][e%roomwidth] is "0" and (e, ns0) not in safetiles:
                            safetiles.append((e, ns0))
```

could speed it up a bit.

## turn `safezone` into `set`

a test `item in list_var` is scanning whole list for `list_var` being a list.

If you turn the test to `item in set_var`, it knows the result almost immediately regardless of size of the `set_var` variable, because `set` has sort of hash which works as "database index" for lookup.

In your code change `safezone = []` into `safezone = set()`

In fact, you can completely skip the membership test in your case:

```
if ns0 not in safezone:
    safezone.append(ns0)
```

can be turned into:

```
safezone.add(ns0)
```

as set will take care of keeping only unique items.

Comment: thank you for catching that!!! I guess when i was iterating the code, i didn't take making it a variable into account

Comment: where would I put the set_var in the code then? do i have to say full "item in set_ver"???

Comment: @SteveZrg no need to introduce `set_ver`, I edited my answer: you shall change `safezone` initialization to `safezone = set()`